# $\underbrace{111\cdots 111}_{1991\,\text{times}}$ is not a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is the question of Belgium mathematical Olympiad $1991$

> Prove that $$\underbrace{111\cdots 111}_{1991\,\text{times}}$$ is not a prime number.

I tried making a computer program to check it but it is too large to fit in that

I am not so strong in congruences, but I can understand  a provided solution regarding CRT or something like that.

Please provide any hint for the first step I should take.

Side note: The question has been marked duplicate but from the link I can only deduce that given number is in the form of $13k+9$ which is not helping me, please provide a comment or something which can help me understanding how can I  use the information given in link.

Comment: Hint: $1991$ is divisible by $11$, use that to factor $x^{1991}-1$.

Comment: Additional hint: Your number can be written as $(10^{1991}-1)/9$

Comment: to add to lulu's hint you can simply use the fact that if the number of one's is divisible by anything other than 1 and itself you can factor the number as a subset of those 1's times another number.

Comment: A slightly simpler example with $33=3\cdot 11$ instead of $1991=11\cdot 180$: $$~~~~111111111111111111111111111111111\\=000000000000000000000011111111111 \\+000000000001111111111100000000000\\+111111111110000000000000000000000$$
The sum on the right hand side is over terms on the form $11111111111\cdot 10^k$ for $k=0,11,22$ which can be factored.

Comment: @lulu I understood your comment but not able to take the question anywhere,, please guide me

Comment: @BillDubuque $1991$ is not  divisible by $6$. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Vidyanshu The methods in the linked dupe work generally, and also apply here. There are probably over 100 dupes of this question.

Comment: I think the other commenters have covered this fairly well.  The key is to write your number as $N=\frac 19\times (10^{1991}-1)$.  Then remark that $11\,|\,1991\implies x^{11}-1\,| \,x^{1991}-1$.  Thus $9N$ is divisible by $10^{11} -1=9\times (10^{10}+10^{9}+\cdots+1)$  which implies that $N$ is divisible by $ 10^{10}+10^{9}+\cdots+1$.

Comment: @BillDubuque, Method used in your answer?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra In both answers

Comment: I was searching Olympiad problem and got this one which seemed interested to me @Math_QED

Comment: @BillDubuque  Almost every single question on this site has duplicates somewhere. In this particular example your link does not answer the same question, although the methods may be similar. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @uniquesolution The question is not exactly identical, but the method to answer it is, viz. they all essentially use $\ x^{\large a}-1\mid x^{\large an}-1\,$ or some close variant. There are already *many* dupes of such. Making more of them is detrimental, since there is by now little novel that can be said on such matters. See [Coping with abstract duplicates.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/coping-with-abstract-duplicate-questions)